# How do I update/rename a table row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, row, alter

I have a table that looks like this:

```
   +-----------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
    | Field     | Type    | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
    +-----------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
    | id        | int(11) | NULL      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l125      | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l250      | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l500      | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l1000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l2000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l4000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l6000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l8000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r125      | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r250      | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r500      | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r1000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r2000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r4000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r6000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r8000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | accountId | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | l3000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    | r3000     | int(11) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
    +-----------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

I would like to modify the table so that I l125 and l250 are removed and I'd like to add a new row with the name l1500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) (note they are columns, not rows that you are changing):

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
    DROP COLUMN l125,
    DROP COLUMN l250,
    ADD COLUMN l1500 INT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER l1000
```

Note I've assumed you want the `l1500` column to have the same definition as the other `lnnn` columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command should look something like:

    `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE row_name='l250';`

and adding new row should be just a general INSERT INTO statement in SQL:

   `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

Check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for INSERT statements and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) for delete statements in SQL. I hope this helps you.